# Offset switch partitions

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have 6 tiles numbered:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
6&5&4&3&2&1\\
0&1&2&3&4&5\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

You must pick one of the numbers from each tile.

I want either the distribution of possible values, or a generating function.

I have worked through this problem myself, I want to know if my results will match yours.

Comment: by 'possible values' you mean something like '052341'?

Comment: yes - well the sum, but order must be preserved for some reason

Comment: so by 'possible values' you mean the sum, not the sequence?

Comment: i thought the seq. is binary

Comment: i've just figured a GF, can I answer my own Q?

Comment: Does the double-3 tile mean there are twice as many possibilities?

Comment: this is a smaller version of the 50-set I am developing, which has 25/25. in it the tops are blue, the base red, so this makes a difference

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: Yes, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the GF is:

$$(1+x^6)(x+x^5)(x^2+x^4)2x^3(x^4+x^2)(x^5+x)$$